# Touch Event of the View behind the Active view is fired in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, events, uitouch

I have created a `viewController` which has a previous and next button on it.
There is a question array, which I pass to this controller. Using the previous and next buttons I navigate through the questions.

Based on the question numbers, the previous and next buttons can be disabled.
For example: If there are three questions; And the first question is on the screen, previous button is disabled and next button is enabled. On the last question, next button is disabled and previous button is enabled.

The issue is, while on the last question the next button is disabled, but if I tap on it, the touch event of the button is triggered on another view behind the active view.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Make object of UIView with same frame of button and clear it's BG color and add as subview.

Comment: i can not change size of view which is behind main view. it is view which contain menu from where i can logout, or open setting etc...

Comment: I think you don't understand my suggestion, wait will post as answer with more descriptions.

Comment: now i got it, its done , thanks jageen.

Comment: Ohh good, you got before i post answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
buttonToBeInactive.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:buttonToBeInactive.frame];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[buttonToBeInactive.superview addSubview:view];
```